# Pandas resampling, percentage values

Tags: python, pandas, resampling

I have a pandas dataframe of monthly observations with datetime index. I would like to convert to yearly observations. The problem is that the values in my dataframe are performance values (for example: monthly pct. change of stock price). How can i resample to yearly values while aggregating correctly?

example of what i would need to to:

```
     m1  0.1     to      q1 0.331
     m2  0.1             q2 0.089
     m3  0.1
     m4 -0.1
     m5  0.1
     m6  0.1
```

monthly to quarterly resampling, 1.1^3-1 = 0.331 , 0.9*(1.1^2)-1 = 0.089

Answer (score 1):

Given that your data resides in a dataframe named `df` with the column `val` holding the integer:

```
(df.val + 1).groupby(df.index // 3).prod() - 1
```

Comment: Thank you, I get the Idea. Im still having some issues because df.values converts my df into a float64 file. However, I'm confident I'll get it working eventually.

Comment: Simply add casts wherever they are needed.

Answer (score 1):

Using the answer of feliks, if you don´t want to change your index, you can apply a regex before grouping:

```
regex_pattern = lambda s: (int(re.search(r'\d+', s).group())-1)//3
d1 = (df.val + 1).groupby(regex_pattern).prod() - 1
```

out:

```
0    0.331
1    0.089
Name: val, dtype: float64
```